# Convert number in scientific notation string to float with limited C-like library

Tags: c, type-conversion, scientific-notation, capl

I'm writing a program in CAPL (which is based on C and minus some concepts) to convert a string containing a number displayed in scientific notation to a float (doesn't strictly need to be a float but I think its an appropriate type for this). For example:

> -7.68000000E-06 should be converted to -0.00000768

I've done some looking around for this and `atof()` comes up a lot but this is not supported in CAPL so I cannot use that.

A list of the other C concepts not supported in CAPL:

[image: CAPL to C - Support Table]

Update: Thanks everyone for the help. [M. Spiller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52383064/9956530) proved to be the easiest solution. I have accepted this answer.

Comment: Is [strtof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) available (from the standard library) ?

Comment: Is type `float` or `double` supported by CAPL?

Comment: As a side note, a literal like `-7.68000000E-06` is actually already valid C. Use `strtod`.

Comment: I guess you can use `strtod` as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482703/how-to-read-a-float-in-a-csv-with-capl).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CAPL the function is called `atodbl` with the same signature as C's `atof`.